# Returning a column name from Information.schema columns and then using that column to find the data within

Tags: c#, sql, information-schema

I have an issue whereby I find the column name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns

```
daISC = new SqlDataAdapter(
    string.Format(
        "SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = 'DynamicDataSubjects' AND ordinal_position = 20"
    ), cn);
```

I then want to use that `colum_name` to find the value of the data within

```
string sColumnName = row2["column_name"].ToString();

daDDS = new SqlDataAdapter(
    string.Format(
        "SELECT '{0}' FROM DynamicDataSubjects WHERE pupil_id = {1} AND interim_id = {2}",
        sColumnName, iPupilID, iInterimID
    ), cn);
```

Unfortunately this throws an error as the `sColumnName` is treated as being text and returns itself. Without the `'{0}'` throws an exception.

Hopefully someone can understand what I'm trying to say and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around `{0}` and it should work. SQL treats characters inside single quotes as string literals. To make sure the column name is properly delimited, i.e., in case it contains spaces, wrap it wit double quotes, e.g.,

`"{0}"`

So:

```
daDDS = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT \"{0}\" FROM DynamicDataSubjects WHERE pupil_id = {1} AND interim_id = {2}", sColumnName, iPupilID, iInterimID), cn);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the single quotes around **'{0}'** ... with quared brackets **[{0}]**

daDDS = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT [{0}] FROM DynamicDataSubjects WHERE pupil_id = {1} AND interim_id = {2}", sColumnName, iPupilID, iInterimID), cn);

This way sColumnName is interpreted as identifier not as text. You also could omit the squared brackets, but that could leave to problems with special characters in column names.